# How to prevent event appointment LOSE on DST - daylight summer time?

Tags: javascript, timezone

Let's say i have a app where the users can make appointments.When DST needs to happen - daylight summer time (in europeran countries - last sunday of March then at midnight on 28 March when 00:00 comes - the time goes on hour forward and then it will be 01:00 ( local time )

If i will have for example some users that maked appointment at 00:45 , does this means that the event is lost, so it will never happen ? How can i handle this ?

Comment: Maybe don't let the appointments be made in the first place?

Comment: It's really up to you on how to handle such a situation.  We can't really define requirements for you.  I've seen some applications skip it, others advance to the next valid time (1:00 in your example), others advance by the amount of the gap (1:45 in your example).  You should figure out which you want, and you'll have to show some code if you need help with the implementation.